# SSL Certificate Verification Error When Scraping Website and Inserting Data into MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, web-scraping, pymongo, langchain

##### Problem Description:

I'm attempting to scrape the website at https://www.cbit.ac.in/current_students/acedamic-calendar/ using the `requests` library along with `BeautifulSoup`. However, upon making a request to the website, I encounter the following SSL certificate verification error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError:
  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.cbit.ac.in', port=443):
    Max retries exceeded with url:
      /current_students/acedamic-calendar/
      (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1,
        '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

##### Approach:

To address the SSL verification issue, I've attempted to specify the path to the CA certificate using the verify parameter in the `requests.get()` function call. The CA certificate path is `/Users/rishilboddula/Downloads/cbit.ac.in.cer`. Despite this, the SSL verification error persists.

After successfully scraping the website, I intend to store the extracted URLs in a MongoDB collection named `ull` using the `pymongo` library. However, due to the SSL verification error, I'm unable to proceed with the scraping and data insertion process.

##### Request for Assistance:

I'm seeking guidance on resolving the SSL certificate verification error to successfully scrape the website and insert the data into MongoDB. Additionally, if there are any best practices or alternative approaches for handling SSL certificate verification in Python, I would greatly appreciate any insights.

```python
# Import necessary libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pymongo

# Specify the path to the CA certificate
ca_cert_path = '/Users/rishilboddula/Downloads/cbit.ac.in.cer'

# Make a request to the website with SSL verification
req = requests.get('https://www.cbit.ac.in/current_students/acedamic-calendar/', verify=ca_cert_path)

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

# Extract all URLs from the webpage
links = soup.find_all('a')
urls = [link.get('href') for link in links]

# Connect to MongoDB
client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
db = client["data"]
ull = db["ull"]

# Insert each URL into the MongoDB collection
for url in urls:
    ull.insert_one({"url": url})
```

Comment: Your HTML handling code works for me without `verify=ca_cert_path` - I can fully populate `urls` without error.  I'm using `Python` version `3.11.8`, `bs4` version `4.12.3`, and `requests` version `2.31.0`.

Comment: FYI, `urls` does not contain unique elements, there are repeats.

Comment: What is the content of `/Users/rishilboddula/Downloads/cbit.ac.in.cer`? The website `www.cbit.ac.in` has a certificate signed by [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), so the `verify` argument would need to point to the [Let's Encrypt root certificate](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/).